# Scanner not scanning input from keyboard for input thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.scanner

I have two threads one thread is monitoring the changes taking place in directory and one thread to ask user to press Y or N to stop monitoring.User can provide input at any point of time say 15 min.
For this I tried using multi-threading but problem is,in input thread scanner is unable to scan input even input appears on the screen but its not accepting that input.
Source Code :

```
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.run();
if(getName().equals("InputScanner")){
    synchronized (this) {
        while(true){
            System.out.print("\nInput Scanner ");
            try {
                {
                    /*String str=*/s1.next();
                    System.out.print("yes");

                }               Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }



    }}
else{
    System.out.print("Thread Id"+getId());
    MonitorDirectory md=new MonitorDirectory();
    md.monitor(path);
}
}
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kJEF.png)

and if Change code `*/*String str=*/s1.next();*`
to

```
if(s1.hasNextLine()){
                    System.out.print("yes");

                }
```

then output is :[SceenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8unbn.png)

Comment: Do you get any errors, or what happens? You have a while true loop, which means it will keep scanning until you break the program. I'd like to see what you're doing with that string you scan or get some more details on what happens after it scans a string.

Comment: I have added screenshot @Memfisto

Comment: `if(getName().equals("InputScanner")){` <- This is **not** how you implement different threads.

Comment: @JimmyB in main I created 2 different objects of this class one to monitor and other to scan input

Comment: I got that, but it's still a very bad idea. Where's `s1` initialized?

Comment: @VarunGoyal can you tell me what's user input for the output on that screenshot?

Comment: @JimmyB in the class outside run method

Comment: By the way, last time I checked, input in the eclipse console could not be accessed by the program running.

Comment: user provides directory path after which monitor starts working and after that user if want to stop monitoring and look for other options then he/she will be pressing N but keyboard input are not detected@Memfisto

Comment: @JimmyB so I should try on cmd ?

Comment: Yes, try it on cmd.

Comment: @JimmyB on cmd I am not able to type input